# Proof check: Given compact $A$, closed $B$ in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$, there are points whose distance is $d(A,B)$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{N}$ be compact and let $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{N}$ be closed. I need to show that there are points $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that
\begin{equation}
d(A,B)=||a-b||,
\end{equation}
where double-bars indicate the usual norm in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ and the $d(A,B)$ denotes the distance between the sets $A$ and $B$ (infimum of the distances of points varying through all points).

Is the following reasoning correct?

I can use that, since $B$ is closed, there is a point $b\in B$ such that
\begin{equation}
d(A,B)=d(A,b).
\end{equation}
Now, we consider the function $A\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $x\mapsto ||x-b||$ and we prove it is continuous. Hence its image is compact in $\mathbb{R}$ and has a minimum. Such minimum gives then the point $a\in A$ I need.

This looks correct to me, but I'm not sure. Is there a shorter proof?

Comment: Looks like a standard argument to me.

Comment: Why do you say $B$ closed implies $d(A,B) = d(A,b)?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As zhw pointed out, one of your claims needs a better justification. However, you can change your argument a bit, to exploit the compactness of $A$ rather than the closedness of $B$.

Since $A$  is compact, there exists an $a_0\in A$ such that $d(a_0, B)=d(A,B)$. Now this claim is fairly straightforward: you can pick $a_n \in A$ and $b_n\in B$ with $\|a_n-b_n\|\rightarrow d(A,B)$. By $A$'s compactness $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ has a convergent subsequence to an $a_0\in A$. Then $a_0$ has the aforementioned property.

Since $\|a_0-b_{k_n}\|\rightarrow d(A,B)$, by the triangle inequality you can see that the sequence $(b_{k_n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded and since you are in $\mathbb{R}^N$, it has a convergent subsequence to a $b_0\in B$. Then $d(a_0,b_0)=d(A,B)$.